# CSS display block and hide another on low resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar and display another thing in it place when the resolution is low and for small screens (mobile)

I did manage to hide the navigation bar but the the other thing won't display.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
        .small-menu {
        display: block;
        }

        .regular-menu {
        display: none;
        }


    }


@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {

        .small-menu {
        display: block;
        }

        .regular-menu {
        display: none;
        }

}


    .small-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .regular-menu {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your  css this seqvence

1. write to your hole page `css`
2. write to your `css` `max-width` **1279**
3. write to your `css` `max-device-width` **500**

```css
      .small-menu {
            display: none;
        }

        .regular-menu {
            display: block;
        }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {

            .small-menu {
            display: block;
            }

            .regular-menu {
            display: none;
            }

    }


    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
            .small-menu {
            display: block;
            }

            .regular-menu {
            display: none;
            }


        }
```

```html
<div class="samll-menu">This is small menu</div>
<div class="regular-menu">This is regular-menu</div>
```

Comment: Writing them this way fixed it.